# why sql server 2008 intellisense showing invalid object name

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

while typing database name intellisense not showing database. after manually typed its showing invalid object name

e.g

```
select * from tbl_customer
```

query executed successfully...
whats wrong ?

Comment: Have you refreshed the IntelliSense cache? In management studio, on the menu go to `Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache (Ctrl + Shift + R)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Management Studio, go to "Edit" and then at the bottom you will see "IntelliSense".
There you will see "Refresh Local Cache".
You can also hit Ctrl+Shift+R as a keyboard shortcut.

This happens if you add an object, such as a table after the environment is already loaded.
After you refresh the local cache, the red underline will be gone.

Elad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you just created the table? The SQL intellisense does not shows newly created objects because the cache of the intellisense has not been updated. Press ' Cntrl + Shift + R ' and the cache will be updated and your table will be seen in it and also it wont show invalid object name